# ProgressTimer is not diplaying on screen in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am using this code to add progressTimer . but its not showing on screen.

```
CCSprite* sprite_HealthBar = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"green_health_bar.png"];
        self.progressTimer = [CCProgressTimer  progressWithSprite:sprite_HealthBar];
        self.progressTimer.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
        self.progressTimer.scale = 5;
        self.progressTimer.percentage = 100;
        self.progressTimer.position =  ccp( winSize.width/2 , winSize.height/2 );
        self.progressTimer.midpoint = ccp(0,0);
        [self addChild:self.progressTimer z:2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
self.progressTimer.barChangeRate = ccp(1,0);

CCProgressTo *to1 = [CCProgressTo actionWithDuration:0.2f percent:100];
[self.progressTimer runAction:to1];
```

Comment: could you explain a bit what you're doing? Changing the changerate to X only?

Comment: Bar change rate x=1 means its horizontal progress bar with no change in y. If y=1 means its vertical progress bar.